# Que tipo de conversão faz o pré-compilador de um SGBD com a linguagem SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

O pré-compilador de um SGBD trata os comandos escritos em SQL.

Supondo que estou usando MySQL.

O que seria feito com o comando:

> select * from cliente;

Que tipo de conversão faz o pré-compilador de um SGBD com a linguagem SQL?

Comment: Acho, não tenho certeza, que vai depender do motor, cada motor deve trabalhar a sua maneira, digamos que ele faz um `parse` da query e transforma no formato especifico pro motor. Note que mysql tem mais de um motor, como innoDB e myisam. O mariaDB também usa outro motor. Não tenho certeza, mas é possivel que não tenha uma resposta definitiva.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O PostgreSQL descreve o processo interno na documentação, no capítulo [47 - Visão Geral do processo Interno](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/parser-stage.html). Informações práticas podem ser encontradas no [Wiki oficial do PostgreSQL](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Query_Parsing).

O [código fonte](https://github.com/winlibs/postgresql/tree/master/src/backend/parser) do parser está disponível no GitHub. Se você entende C, recomendo analisar o código (aviso: o código representa 20 anos de trabalho, então espere uma enorme complexidade, mas maestria).

### O processo

O "estágio de parsing" como é chamado consiste em dois passos:

1. Parsing: cria uma árvore de avaliação e análise seguindo regras sobre a estrutura sintática do SQL passado. O parser usa [bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) e flex (como comparação o PHP também usa bison para análise e parsing léxica).
2. Transformação: faz a interpretação semântica e interpolação com dados da árvore do passo 1.

### Passo 1

1. Verifica se a query possui uma syntax válida (validação do texto "puro" que foi enviado)
2. Se a sintaxe está correta é montada uma árvore de avaliação (parse tree)
3. Essa árvore é iterada com um analisador léxico para reconhecer identificadores (as palavras chaves SQL, etc). Para cada palavra chave ou identificador que é encontrado é gerado um token que é repassado ao parser.

As ações encontradas são transformadas em código C.

### Passo 2

Em suma, faz as ligações de dados do SQL, usando as estruturas criadas no passo 1.

### Acesso à árvore de uma query SQL

Com um programa em C ou Ruby, você pode ter acesso às árvores geradas no processo de parsing. Para isso deve usar a função raw_parser e pode exibí-la formatada usando a função nodeToString.

Um exemplo em C pode ser visto nesse [Gist](https://github.com/pganalyze/queryparser/blob/master/queryparser.c) ou [nesse](https://github.com/pganalyze/queryparser/blob/master/extension/annotate_query.c). Em Ruby você pode usar a Gem [pg_query](https://github.com/pganalyze/pg_query) que gera árvores em JSON.

Exemplo de uma árvore criada a partir de uma query:

```
SELECT * FROM foo where bar = 42 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 23;
(
  {SELECT 
  :distinctClause <> 
  :intoClause <> 
  :targetList (
     {RESTARGET 
     :name <> 
     :indirection <> 
     :val 
        {COLUMNREF 
        :fields (
           {A_STAR
           }
        )
        :location 7
        }
     :location 7
     }
  )
  :fromClause (
     {RANGEVAR 
     :schemaname <> 
     :relname foo 
     :inhOpt 2 
     :relpersistence p 
     :alias <> 
     :location 14
     }
  )
  :whereClause 
     {AEXPR  
     :name ("=")
     :lexpr 
        {COLUMNREF 
        :fields ("bar")
        :location 24
        }
     :rexpr 
        {A_CONST 
        :val 42 
        :location 30
        }
     :location 28
     }
  :groupClause <> 
  :havingClause <> 
  :windowClause <> 
  :valuesLists <> 
  :sortClause (
     {SORTBY 
     :node 
        {COLUMNREF 
        :fields ("id")
        :location 42
        }
     :sortby_dir 2 
     :sortby_nulls 0 
     :useOp <> 
     :location -1
     }
  )
  :limitOffset <> 
  :limitCount 
     {A_CONST 
     :val 23 
     :location 56
     }
  :lockingClause <> 
  :withClause <> 
  :op 0 
  :all false 
  :larg <> 
  :rarg <>
  }
)
```

E exemplo de uma árvore gerada usando a Gem pg_query:

```
#<PgQuery:0x000000009673a0
@query="SELECT * FROM foo where bar = 42 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 23;",
@parsetree=
 [{"SELECT"=>
    {"distinctClause"=>nil,
     "intoClause"=>nil,
     "targetList"=>
      [{"RESTARGET"=>
         {"name"=>nil,
          "indirection"=>nil,
          "val"=>{"COLUMNREF"=>{"fields"=>[{"A_STAR"=>{}}], "location"=>7}},
          "location"=>7}}],
     "fromClause"=>
      [{"RANGEVAR"=>
         {"schemaname"=>nil,
          "relname"=>"foo",
          "inhOpt"=>2,
          "relpersistence"=>"p",
          "alias"=>nil,
          "location"=>14}}],
     "whereClause"=>
      {"AEXPR"=>
        {"name"=>["="],
         "lexpr"=>{"COLUMNREF"=>{"fields"=>["bar"], "location"=>24}},
         "rexpr"=>{"A_CONST"=>{"val"=>42, "location"=>30}},
         "location"=>28}},
     "groupClause"=>nil,
     "havingClause"=>nil,
     "windowClause"=>nil,
     "valuesLists"=>nil,
     "sortClause"=>
      [{"SORTBY"=>
         {"node"=>{"COLUMNREF"=>{"fields"=>["id"], "location"=>42}},
          "sortby_dir"=>2,
          "sortby_nulls"=>0,
          "useOp"=>nil,
          "location"=>-1}}],
     "limitOffset"=>nil,
     "limitCount"=>{"A_CONST"=>{"val"=>23, "location"=>56}},
     "lockingClause"=>nil,
     "withClause"=>nil,
     "op"=>0,
     "all"=>false,
     "larg"=>nil,
     "rarg"=>nil}}],
```